# How to change bold font size to the headings of groups in pickerInput() of shinyWidgets package?

Tags: r, font-face, shinywidgets, pickerinput

I'm building an RShiny-App and now I'm formatting some parts, so they are more readable.
I use `pickerInput()` and want to make the headings`DE` and `AT` bold. I'm using the following `R`-code:

```
 pickerInput(inputId = "ma3DVariables", label = "Select 2 Interesting Variables", 
             choices = list('DE' = c("Munich", "Berin", "Hamburg"),
                            'AT' = c("Vienna", "Graz", "Salzburg")), 
             multiple = TRUE)
```

This gives me at the moment the following:

[image]

How can I make the headings bold? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add [custom style](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html) to a Shiny app:

```
tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".dropdown-header .text { font-weight: bold }")))
```

[image]

Comment: Oh wow, great thank you that's working. Would it be also possible to get a bigger font size for the headers?

Comment: Yes, you can add stuff like `font-size: large;` to the CSS, right after the `font-weight: bold`. I think you need to separate the two with `;`.